# VScode intellisense not working..any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

When I type the code:

```
document.queryselector('.classname').
```

.style and other common suggestions do not appear in the suggested autocomplete menu when I begin to type after the parentheses.

But when I type

```
document.queryselector('body').
```

It does?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should use `querySelector`, not `queryselector`.

Regarding your issue, there is a reason why VScode IntelliSense doesn't show `style` attribute.

Let's look at this example:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.classname')
const element2 = document.querySelector('body')
```

`element` has a type of [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). And `element2` has type [HTMLBodyElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLBodyElement) which is subclass of [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement).

### Element VS HTMLElement

`Element` is the most general base class from which all element objects (i.e. objects that represent elements) in a `Document` inherit. It only has methods and properties common to all kinds of elements. More specific classes inherit from `Element`. And it **doesn't have `style` attribute.**

The `HTMLElement` interface represents any HTML element. It extends `Element` and **has `style` attribute.**

### Then why `element2` return `HTMLBodyElement`?

VSCode has hardcoded typing when you selecting by exact tag name. You can see that in [lib.dom.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/57ebd99ff25b87bcf598f79f506e051f59b8a9c4/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L17630)

### How can fix that?

You can add additional checking and VSCode will understand it:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.classname')

if (element instanceof HTMLElement) {
    element.style.display = 'none'
}
```